# Angular 2/4/5 display dates with suffix (st, rd and th) in expression

Tags: angular

What would be the best "Angular way" to add suffix (st, rd and th) to dates in Angular 2/4/5/... ?

For example: February 25th, March 1st, April 2nd in an Angular expression {{item | date: ???}}

The suffix options do not seem to be covered in the [Angular Date Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) doc.

Comment: If they're not in the doc you probably need to write your own pipe.

Comment: It's a feature request: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14448

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thank you Roddy,

So meanwhile that the Angular team come up with some core feature for date suffixes, here's the simplistic pipe I came up with.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'dateSuffix' })
export class DateSuffix implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string): string {

    let suffix = 'th',
        day = value;

        if (day === '1' || day === '21' || day === '31') {
            suffix = 'st'
        } else if (day === '2' || day === '22') {
            suffix = 'nd';
        } else if (day === '3' || day === '23') {
           suffix = 'rd';
        }

        return suffix;

    }
}
```

and once imported in the component...

I use an expression like this

```
{{record.RecordDate | date: "MMM.d"}} 
<span class="text-superscript">
    {{(record.RecordDate | date: "d") | dateSuffix}}
</span>
```

which outputs something like Apr.3rd

Answer (score 1):

This is not a feature currently supported by Angular -- well, not out-of-the-box.

As you noticed, the Angular Date Pipe [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) does not mention ordinals. Therefore, you will need to write your own pipe to support this functionality and use that in place of the built-in date pipe. I would suggest using the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/pipes/date_pipe.ts) of the date pipe as a starting point, and also the [reference documentation](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes) about writing pipes.

For further reference, note that there is an [open feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14448) for this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I had to solve the same issue and create a pipe as it's relatively straight forward and quicker than submitting/wanting for an Angular bug.  I created an implementation that works for any string that is a number, not just strings less than '31' so it can work with items outside of just dates and is smart if the pipe is misused.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'formatOrder' })
export class FormatOrderPipe implements PipeTransform {

transform(order: any): string {
    const numericValue = (order) ? parseInt(order, 10) : NaN;
    if (!isNaN(numericValue)) {
        // 10-20 numbers all end with 'th' so no need to check anything else
        const twoDigit = numericValue % 100;
        if (twoDigit > 9 && twoDigit < 20) {
            return order + 'th';
        }

        switch (numericValue % 10) {
            case 1:
                return order + 'st';
            case 2:
                return order + 'nd';
            case 3:
                return order + 'rd';
            default:
                return order + 'th';
        }
    }
    return order;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a full date this kind of solution may help 
Ex: ('2019-03-22T18:30:00.000Z')

```
 import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

 @Pipe({ name: 'dateSuffix' })
 export class DateSuffixPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(date: string): string {
        let suffix = 'th';
        const day: string = date.substring(0, 2);
        const monthYear: string = date.substring(2, 15);

      if (day === '1' || day === '21' || day === '31') {
        suffix = 'st';
      }
      if (day === '2' || day === '22') {
        suffix = 'nd';
      }
      if (day === '3' || day === '23') {
        suffix = 'rd';
      }
        const fullDate: string = day + suffix + ' ' + monthYear;
        return fullDate;
    } // transform ()
 } //  class
```

**html**

```
<span>
      <h1>{{ newsPaper.name }}</h1>
      <p>{{ newsPaper.date.substring(0, 10) | date: 'd MMMM y' | dateSuffix }}</p>
</span>
```